# Why is my rails route is a bit off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-admin

I have my root route

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

which is for my home controller and if i visit `http://localhost:3000/` all works great i hit the proper home controller and index action. I then installed this gem [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) But when i visit `http://localhost:3000/admin` i hit the method in my application controller

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
end
```

and get this error, how is it possible that now i have a routing error...any idea

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"home"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in that there's no HomeController in the rails_admin engine which has it's own routing, and somehow it stops there (because there's no such controller in the engine). I'd try using:

```
redirect_to root_url
```

or even this

```
redirect_to '/'
```

This last way means rails doesn't have to try to figure out the path by calling URL for, and might be safer when working with Engines.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referencing your app's routes inside your engine or `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`, you should prefix it with `main_app.`

`redirect_to main_app.root_path, :alert => exception.message`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you don't have your Home Controller defined.

Try adding this above your "root" definition:

```
resources :home, :only => :index
```

I'd also suggest reading the [official Routes guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) on the Rails site.

Comment: i added on top of the root but i got ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"home"}):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `block in <class:ApplicationController>'

Comment: here is my routes.rb   resources :home, :only => :index
  root :to => 'home#index'

Comment: Do a `rake routes` in your app folder, does the root_path route match your home#index?

Comment: here is my route ....                    root        /                              {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}

Comment: Try restarting your rails server. Typically you need to restart after you change the `routes.rb` file.