# Rails_Admin shows Routing Error "No route matches {:controller=>"home"}"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I installed Rails_Admin according to the instructions, and am using Devise as well. When I try to navigate to "/admin" I get the following error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"home"}
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
Ot::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :badgeships
  resources :badges
  resources :profiles
  resources :universities
  resources :degrees
  resources :jobs
  resources :resources
  resources :communities
  resources :networks

  resources :topics do
        resources :posts
  end

  get 'topics/tag/:tag', to: 'topics#index', as: :topic_tag

  get 'resources/tag/:tag', to: 'resources#index', as: :resource_tag

  root :to => 'home#index'

  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

end
```

Here is my rails_admin.rb initializer:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.main_app_name = ["Cool app", "BackOffice"]
  # or somethig more dynamic
  config.main_app_name = Proc.new { |controller| [ "Cool app", "BackOffice - #{controller.params[:action].try(:titleize)}" ] }
end
```

Any idea on how to get rails_admin working properly?

**UPDATED: Here is my rake routes:**

```
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
              badgeships GET    /badgeships(.:format)                      badgeships#index
                         POST   /badgeships(.:format)                      badgeships#create
           new_badgeship GET    /badgeships/new(.:format)                  badgeships#new
          edit_badgeship GET    /badgeships/:id/edit(.:format)             badgeships#edit
               badgeship GET    /badgeships/:id(.:format)                  badgeships#show
                         PUT    /badgeships/:id(.:format)                  badgeships#update
                         DELETE /badgeships/:id(.:format)                  badgeships#destroy
                  badges GET    /badges(.:format)                          badges#index
                         POST   /badges(.:format)                          badges#create
               new_badge GET    /badges/new(.:format)                      badges#new
              edit_badge GET    /badges/:id/edit(.:format)                 badges#edit
                   badge GET    /badges/:id(.:format)                      badges#show
                         PUT    /badges/:id(.:format)                      badges#update
                         DELETE /badges/:id(.:format)                      badges#destroy
                profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)                        profiles#index
                         POST   /profiles(.:format)                        profiles#create
             new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)                    profiles#new
            edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)               profiles#edit
                 profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)                    profiles#show
                         PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)                    profiles#update
                         DELETE /profiles/:id(.:format)                    profiles#destroy
            universities GET    /universities(.:format)                    universities#index
                         POST   /universities(.:format)                    universities#create
          new_university GET    /universities/new(.:format)                universities#new
         edit_university GET    /universities/:id/edit(.:format)           universities#edit
              university GET    /universities/:id(.:format)                universities#show
                         PUT    /universities/:id(.:format)                universities#update
                         DELETE /universities/:id(.:format)                universities#destroy
                 degrees GET    /degrees(.:format)                         degrees#index
                         POST   /degrees(.:format)                         degrees#create
              new_degree GET    /degrees/new(.:format)                     degrees#new
             edit_degree GET    /degrees/:id/edit(.:format)                degrees#edit
                  degree GET    /degrees/:id(.:format)                     degrees#show
                         PUT    /degrees/:id(.:format)                     degrees#update
                         DELETE /degrees/:id(.:format)                     degrees#destroy
                    jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)                            jobs#index
                         POST   /jobs(.:format)                            jobs#create
                 new_job GET    /jobs/new(.:format)                        jobs#new
                edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format)                   jobs#edit
                     job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)                        jobs#show
                         PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)                        jobs#update
                         DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)                        jobs#destroy
               resources GET    /resources(.:format)                       resources#index
                         POST   /resources(.:format)                       resources#create
            new_resource GET    /resources/new(.:format)                   resources#new
           edit_resource GET    /resources/:id/edit(.:format)              resources#edit
                resource GET    /resources/:id(.:format)                   resources#show
                         PUT    /resources/:id(.:format)                   resources#update
                         DELETE /resources/:id(.:format)                   resources#destroy
             communities GET    /communities(.:format)                     communities#index
                         POST   /communities(.:format)                     communities#create
           new_community GET    /communities/new(.:format)                 communities#new
          edit_community GET    /communities/:id/edit(.:format)            communities#edit
               community GET    /communities/:id(.:format)                 communities#show
                         PUT    /communities/:id(.:format)                 communities#update
                         DELETE /communities/:id(.:format)                 communities#destroy
                networks GET    /networks(.:format)                        networks#index
                         POST   /networks(.:format)                        networks#create
             new_network GET    /networks/new(.:format)                    networks#new
            edit_network GET    /networks/:id/edit(.:format)               networks#edit
                 network GET    /networks/:id(.:format)                    networks#show
                         PUT    /networks/:id(.:format)                    networks#update
                         DELETE /networks/:id(.:format)                    networks#destroy
             topic_posts GET    /topics/:topic_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
                         POST   /topics/:topic_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
          new_topic_post GET    /topics/:topic_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
         edit_topic_post GET    /topics/:topic_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
              topic_post GET    /topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                         PUT    /topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                         DELETE /topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
                  topics GET    /topics(.:format)                          topics#index
                         POST   /topics(.:format)                          topics#create
               new_topic GET    /topics/new(.:format)                      topics#new
              edit_topic GET    /topics/:id/edit(.:format)                 topics#edit
                   topic GET    /topics/:id(.:format)                      topics#show
                         PUT    /topics/:id(.:format)                      topics#update
                         DELETE /topics/:id(.:format)                      topics#destroy
               topic_tag GET    /topics/tag/:tag(.:format)                 topics#index
            resource_tag GET    /resources/tag/:tag(.:format)              resources#index
                    root        /                                          home#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/login(.:format)                     devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/login(.:format)                     devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/logout(.:format)                    devise/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize        /users/auth/:provider(.:format)            devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
  user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)     devise/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)              devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)             devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                    devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                   devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                      devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#destroy
             rails_admin        /admin                                     RailsAdmin::Engine

Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
    dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
        index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
          new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
       export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
  bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
history_index GET         /:model_name/history(.:format)         rails_admin/main#history_index
  bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
         show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
         edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
       delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
 history_show GET         /:model_name/:id/history(.:format)     rails_admin/main#history_show
  show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

Here is how I installed rails_admin:

```
    rails g rails_admin:install
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.

           -  Hello, RailsAdmin installer will help you set things up!
           -  I need to work with Devise, let's look at a few things first:
           -  Checking for a current installation of devise...
           -  Found it!
           -  Looks like you've already installed it, good!
           ?  Where do you want to mount rails_admin? Press <enter> for [admin] > manage
        gsub  config/routes.rb
       route  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/manage', :as => 'rails_admin'
           -  And you already set it up, good! We just need to know about your user model name...
           -  We found 'user' (should be one of 'user', 'admin', etc.)
           ?  Correct Devise model name if needed. Press <enter> for [user] > User
           -  Now setting up devise with user model name 'User':
    generate  devise
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.

      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20130214195616_add_devise_to_users.rb
      insert    app/models/user.rb
       route  devise_for :users
           -  Now you'll need an initializer...
           -  You already have a config file. You're updating, heh? I'm generating a new 'rails_admin.rb.example' that you can review.
      create  config/initializers/rails_admin.rb.example
/Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:385:in `block in source_reflection': undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:385:in `collect'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:385:in `source_reflection'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:375:in `rescue in foreign_key'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:373:in `foreign_key'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:292:in `association_foreign_key_lookup'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:72:in `block in associations'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:65:in `map'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:65:in `associations'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/factories/association.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `call'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in factory'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `find'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:54:in `block in factory'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:50:in `each'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:50:in `factory'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:130:in `_fields'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:128:in `_fields'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:108:in `all_fields'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:83:in `fields'
    from (erb):64:in `block in template'
    from (erb):53:in `map'
    from (erb):53:in `template'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `eval'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `result'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:117:in `block in template'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:54:in `call'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:54:in `render'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in invoke!'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in `open'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in `block in invoke!'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:133:in `call'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:133:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:61:in `invoke!'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in `action'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:26:in `create_file'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:116:in `template'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/generators/rails_admin/install_generator.rb:66:in `install'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `each'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `map'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/group.rb:238:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/generators.rb:171:in `invoke'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/iyerushalmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What does `rake routes` in your command line return to you?

Comment: I just added my rake routes to the post above. Looks right to me....what do you think?

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:** Found the fix. See [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670084/1372767).

Go into your main ApplicationController and change

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |e|
  redirect_to root_path, alert: e.message
end
```

to

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |e|
  redirect_to '/', alert: e.message
end
```

Giving it *any* symbolic path name will cause a RoutingException, since Rails is looking for the name in the *wrong routing table*. Specifying a literal root path bypasses the lookup, and gives the main application's ApplicationController first crack at dealing with it. Which is what you want.

Original post below the `hr`:

---

I'm encountering a similar error, where if a non-admin user accesses my '/admin' route, then ActiveAdmin+CanCan tries to kick him out. (You get much more legible error reporting by adding the `better_errors` Gem, by the way.) I get the exception report, and I can see the correct error message in the local variables at the point where the routing failure happens.

I can also see, thanks to better_errors' "live shell", that the ActionController generating the RoutingError is `RailsAdmin::MainController`. This suggests to me that we need to figure out how to tell RailsAdmin to redirect to the *application* root path, not the *engine* root path.

Comment: Note: To accomplish with a named route, use main_app.root_path to use the routes from your main app.

Comment: adding to the point above, to make the rails_admin redirect_to root path. do redirect_to '/' instead of redirect_to root_path

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your routing is not working is because you injected

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

at the bottom of the `routes.rb` file. Understand that routes take a priority from top to bottom. When an url is routed, it will begin at the top of the list and go down. As soon as it spots the matching route, Rails will send it off to the appropriate controller and action.

Generally, I find it best practice to move third-party-api at the top of the API list. If there ends up being a conflict issue, I can then change out my own created routes. Much easier to deal with.

So move the Devise and RailsAdmin routes to the top and tell us what you get.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I tried this but am still receiving the same routing error. What else could be causing this?

Comment: What happens if you take out `root :to => 'home#index'`? Do you actually have a controller titled `home` set up in the controllers folder?

Comment: I do have a home controller, so if I remove it I get this error "No route matches [GET] "/"   when I navigate to my homepage, and I get this error when I navigate to /admin "undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RailsAdmin::MainController:0x007f9d60d6dfa8>"

Comment: when I ran "bundle exec rake db:migrate" after installing rails_admin I received the following: "[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it."  Is this a problem?

Comment: No that's not an issue. Honestly, I can't come up with a reason why it's not working. Hopefully someone else will shed light on your problem. If you haven't already, go ahead and reinstall Rails Admin and make sure that you are configuring everything appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I tried installing it again and I posted above the output I get. Let me know if anything else comes to mind. Thanks

Comment: I would seriously take a look at the list of errors produced from Rails Admin installation. You could have messed up writing a foreign key within a database or have made a mistake setting your associations between your models. Rails Admin works best after your models are all set up.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the devise and admin routes to the top of the routes file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this and it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, but it only occurs when I'm signed in with my User model. If I'm not signed in it redirects to my sign_in page.

**Update**

What was happening to me was that my user model wasn't allowed to `:manage` the resources the dashboard accesses.

Once I included this authorization, the admin panel worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `main_app` in the `routes.rb` to refer to main app route as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancancan).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to main_app.root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end
end
```